# Звуковое сопровождение на сайте

Tags: php, html, mp3

Привет всем, столкнулся с проблемой в том что есть 3 трека {1.mp3,2.mp3,3.mp3}

Так вот необходимо сделать так что-бы по рандому играла одна из выше приведенных мп3шек на страничке сайта (фишка в том что должна быть кросс-браузерность) (проигрователь если таковой будет необходимо что-бы был невидим для человеческого глаза (исключая исходный код)

Кто что предложит?

(возможность использовать "JS/HTML/PHP/MySQL/CSS/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо хорошую совместимость, советую использовать готовые решения, например одно из лучших: http://jplayer.org/ умеет многое,

- по сути один JS файлик,  занимает
     около 8кб если браузер позорный,
     подключает Flash? а по умолчанию
     HTML5

цитата, где поддерживается:

- Windows: Firefox, Chrome, Opera,
     Safari, IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 OSX:
     Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Opera iOS:
     Mobile Safari: iPad, iPhone, iPod
     Touch Android: Android 2.3 Browser
     Blackberry: OS 7 Phone Browser,
     PlayBook Browser

Про звуки поддерживает и Mp3 и

- HTML5: mp3, mp4 (AAC/H.264), ogg
     (Vorbis/Theora), webm (Vorbis/VP8),
     wav Flash: mp3, mp4 (AAC/H.264), flv

грех не пользоваться, и не изобретать велосипеды.
Подставляй рандомы как хочешь.
Единственное - придется разобраться, как его подключить, но это разовый труд, зато потом сможешь подключать куда попало и радовать посетителей.

А да, я тоже не сторонник музыки по умолчанию, однако всякие сайты бывают ведь.

Comment: путь даст пользователям переключатель вида выключить включить и все будет нормально =)

Comment: http://best-hoster.ru - пример неразумного включения музыки (хостер, сайт для предоставления совсем другой услуги, никак не MP3 плеера)
http://tochnoe-vremya.ru - пример разумного включения, радио включается сразу же, и то первый раз оно само не включится, а включится только если пользователь сам выбрал в прошлый раз станцию.

Comment: Мне понравилась формулировка мысли "если браузер позорный" :D

Comment: Ага, есть еще предприятия где люди за Windows98 сидят и не гудят.

Comment: Да, сам не сторонник музыки на веб-сайтах. Но проблема в том что это будет что-то вроде обучения по сайту в разных вариациях (главная страница 3 вариации... и т.п) Спасибо всем за ответы последний из них показался более - менее подходящим.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 :)

А вообще очень ненавижу когда на странице без моего участия играет какая-то мелодия, сразу закрываю страницу такую!

Comment: фишка в том что должна быть кросс-браузерность

Фишка в том что HTML5 это не про кросс-браузерность

Comment: Ну я более подробно расписал что звук на страничке - это fake! :)

Answer (score 2):

Кроссбраузерность может гарантировать **только** flash, а генерить случайное число от 1 до 3 это совсем не проблема, сделать проигрыватель невидимым тем более.